# How to change redmine attachment directory on xen server ubuntu virtual machine

Tags: ubuntu, directory, attachment, redmine

- I've created new virtual disk on xen cerver vm.
- mount it for the new directory as /mnt/newdisk and create file /mnt/newdisk/redmine/files
- i want to attach any files to /mnt/newdisk not /usr/share/redmine/files

Answer (score 1):

New mounted disk part (should be same as redmine/files permisions and owners):

```
cd /mnt
chmod 755 /newdisk
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data newdisk
```

Configuration part:

```
cd /usr/share/redmine/config
sudo nano configuration.yml
```

Paste it:

```
attachments_storage_path: /mnt/newdisk/redmine/files
```

Save and Exit:
CTRL+X and Y